Does DispatchProxy.Invoke work only on the interface methods calls?
For the static DispatchProxy.Create<T,TProxy>() the documentation tells us that:

Creates an object instance that derives from class TProxy and
implements interface T.

Having the following testing code confirms that:
interface I{
    void Foo();
}

class D : DispatchProxy {
    protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("In Invoke");
        return null;
    }
    public virtual void DMethod(){
    }
}

var proxy = DispatchProxy.Create<I,D>();
Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetType().BaseType); // typeof(D)
Console.WriteLine(proxy is I); // true

Then the interesting part about the Invoke method according to the docs:

Whenever any method on the generated proxy type is called, this method
is invoked to dispatch control.

This could mean
proxy
.GetType()
.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Static)
.Select(x => x.Name)

which gives us
Foo
Invoke
DMethod
GetType
MemberwiseClone
Finalize
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
but if we test whether we have Invoke called for both the interface method and the dispatch class method:
proxy.Foo(); // In Invoke
((D)proxy).DMethod(); // nothing

Looking at how DispatchProxy's generated proxy type is implemented with a private field with an array of MethodInfos that are used in the stub methods with calls to Invoke it will make sense that we should only be able to have this behavior with methods we can override.
That's why I have defined the DMethod as virtual, but apparently no stub was created.
Does this mean that the docs should state:

Whenever any >>>interface method on the generated proxy type is
called, this method is invoked to dispatch control.


Changing "any method" to "any interface method" would still be inaccurate.
Suppose there is a second interface I2, and D implements that.
var proxy = DispatchProxy.Create<I,D>();
((I2)proxy).Bar();

interface I2 {
    void Bar();
}

class D : DispatchProxy, I2 {
    protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("In Invoke");
        return null;
    }

    public virtual void Bar() {}
}

The call to Bar (clearly an "interface method") does not cause Invoke to be called either.
I would interpret "the generated proxy type" as typeof(I), instead of proxy.GetType(), since that is the return type of Create.
This matches the implementation of Create, where only the methods of T (the first type parameter of Create) and its superinterfaces are taken into account. (source)
Of course, I agree that the documentation could be worded better. A more accurate (but IMO more convoluted) wording would be:

Whenever any method of the interface type I is called, this method is invoked to dispatch control, where I is the interface type passed to the Create call that created this proxy.


Side note: getting/setting properties/indexers of the interface, and adding/removing event handlers of events of the interface would also cause Invoke to be called. But these operations are technically still calling some kind of methods "under the hood" at the IL level. So from a C# language point-of-view, it's not just "any method". That said, if the documentation mentioned all these possibilities, it would become even more convoluted.

Rereading the doc for the 10th time, I think the keyword here is ON:  "any method on the generated proxy type". If we call GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods we would just get the interface (we mock) method Foo(). And I don't think it's just the required, i.e. abstract methods - it will reflect emit IL for an interface method that has a default implementation.

also I like your definition, convoluted > confusing imo
